# Angular2 Firestore: How to search in array

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am learning Angular and trying to use Firestore through angular2-firestore. I created 2 collections structured as this:

```js
    export interface Account {
      uid: string;
      title: string;
      startDate: Date;
      endDate: Date;
      manager: User;
      members: User[];
    }

    export interface User {
      uid: string;
      email: string;
      displayName: string;
      isActive: boolean;
    }
```

Now I need to query accounts by a user who is member in it. What I could do is fetch all of the accounts and then filter them using Typescript code, but I thought there should be some more efficient way to do this. Anybody please help. Thanks in advance.

#### Update

In my service, I added a method like this:

```js
    @Injectable()
    export class AccountService {
    private static ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME = 'accounts';
    
      constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
      }
    
      public getAllOpenAccountsIAmIn(user: User) {
        return this.db.collection(AccountService.ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME, ref => {
          return ref.where('endDate', '==', null)
            // .where('members', 'contains', user); -- this is what I want something like
        }).valueChanges();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

change your structure like this

```js
export interface Account {
  uid {
    uid: string;
    title: string;
    startDate: Date;
    endDate: Date;
    manager: User;
    members: User[];
  }
}

export interface User {
  uid {
    uid: string;
    email: string;
    displayName: string;
    isActive: boolean;
  }
}
```

in your service

```
.where('uid.members', '==', user)
```

for reference  watch this video till the end
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdKEhWAV-kE&t=3s